# Stack around the variable fib was corrupted

Tags: c++, assembly

I got this function here written in x86 to calculate and fill an array with fibonacci sequence numbers. It stores and prints the numbers correctly, but it shows a "Stack around the variable 'fib' was corrupted"

Do you know why this happen? This is my code.I work on MVS 2020. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

void fibonacci() {

    unsigned int fib[2000];



    __asm {
    init:
        mov EAX, 0      // num
        mov EBX, 1          // snum
        mov ECX, 0          // res
        mov EDX, 0      // contador
        mov ESI, 0          // index


        mov[fib + ESI * 4], EAX
        mov[fib + ESI * 4 + 4], EBX

        add ESI, 2

        JMP tst

    lp:
        mov ecx, 0          // Reinicialitzem "res"
        add ecx, eax        // Sumem a res, num
        add ecx, ebx        // Sumem a res, snum

        mov[fib + ESI * 4], ecx     // movem al vector el resultat
        mov eax, ebx                // num = snum
        mov ebx, ecx                // snum = res

        add edx, 1                  // incrementem el contador
        add ESI, 1              // Incrementem l'index


        tst:
        cmp edx, 2000
        jl lp

        exit :
}


for ( int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    cout << fib[i] << " ";


    


}



int main() {

 fibonacci();

}
```

Comment: Fortunately you can debug your inline asm code in VS too

Comment: You're off-by-two. You add two to the index (`esi`) but not the counter (`edx`) initially. So the counter goes from 0 at the start of the first iteration to 1999 at the start of the last iteration. That means you write 2002 entries, not 2000 entries. Your array only has 2000 entries.

Comment: @ecm THANK YOU VERY MUCH, YOU'RE THE BEST :)

Comment: You could have avoided this bug by simplifying your logic to just use `ESI < 2000` as the loop condition; you're already using an array index instead of just a pointer increment.

Answer (score 1):

My `ASM` is rusty, but it looks like you are making 1,999 steps, but you start with `ESI` of 2.